# How to build a custom user mention functionality for TinyMCE editor in Angular

Tags: angular, tinymce, editor

I am trying to customize the TinyMCE editor and want to add user mention functionality like this in the following image:

[image]

TinyMCE provides this in its premium subscription. But I want to build this by own. I can easily add this functionality to a simple input using [angular-mention](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-mentions). But this package is not working with the TinyMCE editor. How can I add user mention functionality in the TinyMCE editor?

I want that if I type '@' symbol in the TinyMCE editor, it would trigger a list of usernames (with the matching name as a typed string after @) in the dropdown, and the user can select one of the usernames.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I added some more description.